# Modify stylus behavior in any tablet

Tags: autohotkey, stylus-pen

I just read this post about there being no way to fully use the stylus buttons, nor movements:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91828-stylus-middle-mouse-button-emulation/

And I think that there should be some available workaround for this by now.

To clearly state my question: Is there a way to use AutoHotkey (or other program) to modify the stylus buttons (including the on screen actions like click and hold) in a similar fashion as the keyboard?

An example of what I am looking for in AutoHotkey is to be able to press pen against screen and at the same time click any button as a hotkey using e.g. GetKeyState.

Comment: You need to find out what "key" code it uses start an autohotkey program and go see in the key history to find the key code?

Comment: I am considering whether I should buy a tablet, and whether or not the stylus even is supported by AutoHotkey is part of that decision. So yes, if someone who has one could give an example of how they solved this, or (if it is not possible) say that it is not possible that would answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

One suboptimal workaround that I know for this is to use something like these: http://alternativeto.net/software/strokesplus/

And have them send some keyboard combination as output, which AutoHotkey can act on. This would probably work, but would require another program, and essentially make AutoHotkey redundant for the most basic things. Once you add GetKeyState etc functionality from AutoHotkey the two together should make for a vast amount of possible combinations not possible by either alone though.